# Jenkins Workflow: How to get or set step id

Tags: jenkins-workflow

We would like to reference a step inside a parallel task of a Jenkins workflow. But it seems that step IDs are created non deterministic for steps in multiple parallel tasks. For a input step it is possible to manually specify the step id. Is it either possible to specify a step id for a shell step or query the step id?

The purpose is that we would like to create a link to a shell script inside a parallel task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed step IDs are not in general predictable in advance. Do you want to link to its log, like [this](https://jenkins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/core/job/acceptance-test-harness-wf/lastSuccessfulBuild/execution/node/31/log/)? I am not entirely clear about the use case.

The closest existing RFE would be [JENKINS-28119](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28119).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use the input ID instead of step ID:

```
node {
  input id: 'input1', message: 'Continue?'
}
```

Then the input URL would exposed as:

```
http://[jenkins_base_URL]/job/[job_name]/[build_id]/input/Input1/proceedEmpty
```

(Note the capitalization on the input ID).

Comment: We need the step id for a shell step not for an input step. I mentioned input only because there it is possible. And we either need something similar for shell (or a way to query).

Comment: There is no generic id for steps. What's your specific need?