# Pipeline input step field "inputId" in Jenkins - API

Tags: api, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[Screenshot of pipeline-input-step (Proceed or Abort)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbOiZ.png)

I could not figure out how is generated [pipeline-input-step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) url parameter **inputId** which contains string similar to CRUMB (CSRF protection) or API TOKEN - it is not any of these. However main purpose of it is to use it in GUI, I would like to know how to initiate it through terminal as well.
Example of url (in POST method):

```
http://my-jenkins-url.com/job/NAME_OF_THE_JENKINS_JOB/6/wfapi/inputSubmit?inputId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38827523/jenkins-input-pipeline-step-filled-via-post-with-csrf-howto

Comment: Unfortunately it does not describe, how inputId is generated. It is not CRUMB or API TOKEN either.

Comment: That's true, sorry my bad. What about giving those inputs an id? Like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32694427/2791574

Comment: Not a solution, but meanwhile I turned off CSFR Protection and checked network log and found a solution. The reason was, that my POST request did not contained json form. What I can not still solve, is what is basis of inputId. Is it changing in the time? How is it generated?
`curl -X POST -H $CRUMB "http://my-jenkins-url.com/job/NAME_OF_THE_JENKINS_JOB/6/wfapi/inputSubmit?inputId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" \

 --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": []}' `

Comment: Forgive my necrocommenting :) What @PavolTravnik suggested does look like solution. Valid crumb can be obtained from `https:/MY_JENKINS_RUL/crumbIssuer/api/json`