# How to specify a custom url for Github status checks in a Jenkins Blue Ocean stage?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

When running a stage in a Jenkinsfile I would like to be able to change the URL that is reported back to Github. By default it appears to be the URL to the build in Jenkins, but I would like to append something to that url like `/aSpecificReport.html`.

I can do this with the githubNotfiy plugin as such:

```
githubNotify context: 'Lint',
             status: 'FAILURE',
             description: 'ESLint found errors',
             targetUrl: env.BUILD_URL + '/aSpecificReport.html'
```

But is there a way to do this for a specific step without using the githubNotifiy plugin?

For reference, this is the "status check link" I'm referring to:

[image: this is the "status check link"]

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in the same effect and it appears that the stage ids are not predictable before the pipeline is run (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33402876/6943587), as I would assume they depend on the stage configuration, stage count, parallelization, nesting, etc. However, I noticed that the ids for stages are consistent between identical, or nearly identical, pipeline runs.

For example, if you create a PR (#22) that triggers a pipeline run. Then later you pushed a new commit to that branch, triggering another pipeline run. The stage ids between those two runs will be identical, provided they have a similar, if not identical, pipeline flow (i.e. they both triggered/skipped the same stages). Then the only difference between the urls to each stage would be the `BUILD_ID`.

Therefore, the url for the first and second stage for both `BUILD_ID`s would be...

`BUILD_ID` = 1

```
# Stage 1
https://<jenkins-host>.com/blue/organizations/jenkins/<repo>/detail/PR-22/1/pipeline/15`

# Stage 2
https://<jenkins-host>.com/blue/organizations/jenkins/<repo>/detail/PR-22/1/pipeline/45
```

`BUILD_ID` = 2

```
# Stage 1
https://<jenkins-host>.com/blue/organizations/jenkins/<repo>/detail/PR-22/2/pipeline/15`

# Stage 2
https://<jenkins-host>.com/blue/organizations/jenkins/<repo>/detail/PR-22/2/pipeline/45
```

Granted, this is not ideal as it would require validating and updating stage ids for major changes to the pipeline and would not be suitable for highly variable pipeline flows. But it has worked for me so thought I'd share.